# Angular click event on component send inner element as target

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a click event on an Angular component:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  template: `
    <hello (click)="onClick($event)"></hello>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  onClick(e) {
    alert("Click on TAG: " + e.target.tagName);
  }
}
```

See demo online: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zxmsnc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Why is `event.target` an inner element of the component and not the component itself?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's because `event.target` refers to **the element that triggered the event**.

I think you're looking for `event.currentTarget` which refers to **the element that the event listener is attached to**.